Format VSCode Debug Console output

In the above I am running my GO application in the terminal and piping the output to jq which formats it nice and readable. I'd like to be able to do something similar (or use a plugin if one is available) to the same effect in the debug console when running from the debug tool so I can have pretty output while stepping through. I've toyed with running dlv from the cmd (piped to jq) and attaching to process but this doesn't seem viable.
Is it possible to apply some formatting or customisation to the Debug Console?

